# Move from Newtonsoft.Json to System.Text.Json and Guid problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, system.text.json

I have a .NET 5 ASP REST service and I'm trying to remove Newtonsoft with System.Text.
Problem is that with Newtonsoft I was able to send GUID's without dashes and the model was bonded successfully, now I get nulls (with System.Text.Json)

I was able to isolate the problem using https://dotnetfiddle.net/ocayBp

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //this works
        var json = "{\"AuthorId\":\"6917d697-c1ab-4fb7-b297-8b2a23100bfc\",\"Title\":\"test title\"}";
        //this doesn't work
        //var json = "{\"AuthorId\":\"6917d697c1ab4fb7b2978b2a23100bfc\",\"Title\":\"test title\"}";
        var result1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(json);
        result1.Dump();
        var result2 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Post>(json);
        result2.Dump();
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Newtonsoft correctly deserialized string to GUID, with System.Text.Json approach I get this error:

> Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value
> could not be converted to System.Guid. Path: $.AuthorId | LineNumber:
> 0 | BytePositionInLine: 46.  ---> System.FormatException: The JSON
> value is not in a supported Guid format.    at
> System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.GetGuid()    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.GuidConverter.Read(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack&
> state, T& value)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader&
> reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    --- End of
> inner exception stack trace ---    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state,
> Utf8JsonReader& reader, Exception ex)    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1
> utf8Json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, Nullable`1 actualByteCount)    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadFromSpan[TValue](ReadOnlySpan`1
> json, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json,
> JsonSerializerOptions options)    at Program.Main()

I'm setting up JSON in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddControllers(
    options =>
    {
        options.ValueProviderFactories.Add(new ClaimValueProviderFactory());
    }).AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull;
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});
```

How can I get the same behavior with `System.Text.Json` as with `Newtonsoft.Json`.

I found an issue on GitHub(https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30692) but there is no `TryGetGuid` method where you can specify the format.

Comment: Your fiddle fails because the GUID doesn't have any dashes in it. Is your code example the wrong way around (works vs not)?

Comment: when I send GUID without dashes I get an exception. The point is that Newtonsoft supports GUID's with and without dashes. I'd like to get the same behavior with System.Text.Json.

Comment: That's not standard. You need to write a override the default converter with a custom one. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to)

Comment: @JHBonarius I just did that

Answer (score 2):

We can try to write a customer JsonConverter for `Guid` by [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-6.0)

```
public class GuidJsonConverter: JsonConverter<Guid>
{
    public override Guid Read(
            ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
            Type typeToConvert,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                Guid.Parse(reader.GetString()!);

    public override void Write(
            Utf8JsonWriter writer,
            Guid value,
            JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
                writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
}
```

Then try to add convert to the property by `JsonConverter` Attribute.

```
public class Post
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(GuidJsonConverter))]
    public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

[c# online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VNIjfb)

Answer (score 2):

I created a custom converter:

```
public sealed class JsonConverterGuid : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<Guid>
{
    public override Guid Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TryGetGuid(out Guid value))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("guid");
            return value;
        }

        if (reader.TryGetString(out string str))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("string");
            return Guid.Parse(str);
        }

        throw new FormatException("The JSON value is not in a supported Guid format.");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Guid value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static bool TryGetString(this Utf8JsonReader je, out string parsed)
    {
        var(p, r) = je.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.String => (je.GetString(), true),
            JsonTokenType.Null => (null, true),
            _ => (default, false)};
        parsed = p;
        return r;
    }
}
```

Maybe GUID without dashes isn't a standard, but I want to be compatible with Newtonsoft. I'm posting the answer, because someone might have the same error as I did.

and used it like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K9UXpb